# Missing templete error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

the following link_to is in my landings/index.html.erb. The link appears correctly on the landing page, when I click the link it says:

```
 ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template landings/faq, application/faq with
 Searched in:   * "/app/app/views"
```

landings/index.html.erb

```
 <%= link_to "Learn more by reading our Frequently Asked Questions", faq_path %>
```

Landings controller app/controllers/landings_controller.rb

```
 class LandingsController < ApplicationController

    def about

    end

    def contact

    end

    def faq

    end

    def terms

    end

    def privacy 

    end

    def blog

    end


  end
```

routes.rb

```
 root :to => "landings#index"
  match '/about',    to: 'landings#about'
  match '/contact',  to: 'landings#contact'
  match '/faq',      to: 'landings#faq'
  match '/terms',    to: 'landings#terms'
  match '/privacy',  to: 'landings#privacy'
  match '/blog',     to: 'landings#blog'
```

the routes to about and contact all work fine and I will include how I call them below. It is just the faq view that can not be found, which I will also include where the view is. (the link does find the view in my localhost environment, just not production) I am deploying my application using Heroku.

views/landings/faq.html.erb does exist

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Due to what I see in the post, rails search in `app/app/views` and you may only have `app/views/landings/faq.html.erb` . Try to copy the file to `app/app/views/landings/faq.html.erb` to see if it works.

Comment: The thing is I don't have an app/app folder...would you recommend creating an app/app folder and putting the view in there?

Comment: Can you try rendering the template manually in faq action? `render :template => "landings/faq"`